# How to combine multiple filters in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, filtering

I would like to combine some filters in my Vue app:

```
        app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                products: null,
                productGroups: null,
                productPackageWeights: null,
                checkedProductGroupItems: [],
                checkedProductPackageWeights: [],
            },
            created: function created() {
                this.fetchData();
            },
            computed: {
                productsFilter: function () {
                    return this.filterProductGroupItems;
                }
            },        
            methods: {
                fetchData: function () {
                    var vm = this
                    axios.get([MY_JSON_FILE])
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response.data.filter_data.product_package_weights);

                        vm.productPackageWeights = response.data.filter_data.product_package_weights;
                        vm.productGroups = response.data.filter_data.product_groups;
                        vm.products = response.data.products;
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        alert('Het ophalen van de producten is niet gelukt');
                    });
                },
                filterProductGroupItems: function(data) {
                    if (this.checkedProductGroupItems.length == 0) return true;
                    return this.checkedProductGroupItems.includes(data.features.product_groups.value);
                },  
                filterProductPackageWeights: function(data) {
                    if (this.checkedProductPackageWeights.length == 0) return true;
                    return this.checkedProductPackageWeights.includes(data.features.product_package_weights);
                },                                      
            }
        });
```

The code works only for the **filterProductGroupItems**. How can I combine the **filterProductGroupItems** and **filterProductPackageWeights** results in the computed **productsFilter** function? I'm also planning to make some more filter functions.

Please help
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
computed: {
    productsFilter: function () {
        return [...this.filterProductGroupItems(), ...this.filterProductPackageWeights()];
    }
},
```

or `concat`

```
computed: {
    productsFilter: function () {
        return this.filterProductGroupItems().concat(this.filterProductPackageWeights());
    }
},
```

the problem may be that you could end up with an array that has [true, Obj, Obj ...] if one filter returns true, so you may want to change the filter to return an empty array

```
filterProductGroupItems: function(data) {
    if (this.checkedProductGroupItems.length == 0) return [];
    return this.checkedProductGroupItems.includes(data.features.product_groups.value);
},  
filterProductPackageWeights: function(data) {
    if (this.checkedProductPackageWeights.length == 0) return [];
    return this.checkedProductPackageWeights.includes(data.features.product_package_weights);
},
```